# On a 2007 Ford Galaxy Clutch Replacement

Tags: ford, clutch, galaxy

On a 2007 Diesel Ford Galaxy, Do you need to replace the dual mass flywheel also along with the clutch.
Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

As an owner of a Jaguar x-type who follows the jag forum where the same issue is discussed at length.

The best advice is to replace the dmf and clutch all at the same time, also cleaning the starter motor as necessary.

This is due to the time and expense of getting to the bits - some who did just the clutch found themselves paying again 12 months later for the dmf...

The other point is to purchase LUK original parts - cheap copies fail early, but it is your money and choice.